# Restrict access to route if user is "privileged"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, routes

Will probably be my last post as this is the last issue I am having with my code...

In Mongo, I have a “privileged” document, which is set to false for some users. If a particular user has this privileged field as false, I only want them to access one part of the platform which is the code in my app.js file down below:

```
<PrivateRoute path = "/training-centre" component = {Training} />
```

Can I have some sort of if statement in my app.js which checks to see if a user is privileged, and then just have that route inside the if statement? So something like this:

```
const App = (userData) => {
 const {isLoading} = useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Router>

          <Route exact path = "/" component= {Login} />
          {userData.privileged == false && (
          <Route exact path="/training-centre" component={Training} />
        )}
```

Not sure on the best way to achieve what I am trying to do…

The rest of the code...

```
const App = (userData, props) => {
  const {isLoading} = useAuth0();
  const privileged = useSelector(state => state.user.privileged);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (props.privilegedOnly) {
    if (privileged !== true) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={'/training-centre'} />
      );
    }
  }
          
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <switch>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path = "/" component= {Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/decision-style" component = {DecisionStyle} />
          <Route path = "/area-of-expertise" component = {AreaOfExpertise} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/dashboard" component = {Dashboard} />
          <Route path = "/news" component = {News} />
          <Route path = "/malwareNews" component = {malwareNews} />
          <Route path = "/phishingNews" component = {phishingNews} />
          <Route path = "/mobileSecurityNews" component = {mobileSecurityNews} />
          <Route path = "/passwordNews" component = {passwordNews} />
          <Route path = "/searchBar" component = {searchBar} />
          <Route path = "/searchResults" component = {searchResults} />

          <Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact}>
          {props.children}
          </Route>

          <PrivateRoute path = "/training-centre" component = {Training} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/training" component = {TrainingSection} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/ask-an-expert" component = {AskAnExpert} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/practice-arena" component = {PracticeArena} />
          <Route path = "/about-us" component = {AboutUs} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/maze-game" component = {MazeGame} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/whack-a-hacker" component = {WhackAHacker} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/whackahacker-gameover" component = {HackerGameOver} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/quiz" component = {Quiz} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/card-swiper" component = {CardSwiper} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/cyber-crossword" component = {CyberCrossword} />
        
        </Router>
        </switch>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using something similar from here but no luck:
https://medium.com/craft-academy/how-to-restrict-your-routes-and-links-in-react-js-now-with-hooks-12b395c1a2fe

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `PrivateRoute` component like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  // Using redux in this example, but you could get this info by passing as a prop
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuthenticated);
  const isPrivileged = useSelector(state => state.user.isPrivileged);

  if (isAuthenticated === false) {
    return (
      <Redirect to={props.loginRoute} />
    );
  }

  if (props.privilegedOnly) {
    if (isPrivileged !== true) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={'/'} />
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact}>
      {props.children}
    </Route>
  );
}
```

Be aware that, for this to work, you should wrap all your `Route` and `PrivateRoute` components inside a `<Switch />` ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch)), otherwise this logic would run without existing a route match.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! I'm now getting this weird error which when I looked up suggested I was not using react-router-dom which I am...? I uploaded the rest of my code if it helps!